# Making a .bat file which compiles C++

Tags: python, c++, batch-file, cmd

I would like to automate the process of typing

`g++ -o filename.exe filename.cpp`

Here is some python code to do it:

```
import os

filename = input("File name: ")

fo = open("compile.bat", "w")
fo.write("g++ -o " + str(filename) + ".exe " + str(filename) + ".cpp")
fo.close()

os.system("compile.bat")
```

Basically, it asks the user to input the name of his file and then makes a `.bat` file with all the details. The new `.bat` file is then told to start and the command inside it compiles the program.

The code inside the new `.bat` file is:

```
g++ -o your_file_name.exe your_file_name.cpp
```

Theoretically speaking, I can do the same with any language such as Java, C++ or Ruby, **but** what if I **don't want to** use any language? My question is how can I do all this in the same batch-file which passes the details to the compiler?

What I basically want is to make a batch-file which:

- Asks the user to enter their file's name.
- Calls the command to compile the file.

[image]

Comment: Hello downvoter, please tell me what's wrong with my question.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but several things. There's a lack of capitalization (with other grammatical oddities); there's way too much fluff text; it's not particularly clear what the *problem* that you are having is as this isn't a code-writing service (www.what-have-you-tried.whatever). It's not a terrible question, but it's hardly perfect.

Comment: Do you know that tools like make or nmake exists explicitely for that usage, and allow for multiple source files, additional libraries, recompile only modified source and so on and so forth. Do you really want to comete with such tools ? And in the simple case, `make foo` look if there is in current directory a `foo.c` or `foo.cpp` compiles and links with standard options and produces `foo` (Unix world) or `foo.exe` (Windows world).

Comment: @Veedrac thank you for pointing out my mistakes, I will try to be better in the future (grammar and stuff) :D

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am aware of the tools which exist and yes, I wish to compete since in this world we survive by competing with others. XD

Comment: For smaller tasks making ad-hoc scripts is ok but they don't scale at all well with project size. I would suggest looking into the pre-existing build tools out there if you embark on any sort of larger project. This is because they can check dependencies and conditionally build only what's needed. I wouldn't use make though, especially on windows, there are more modern tools that have fewer shortcomings and are much more cross platform friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically a three-liner:

stop command repetition (for nicer output):

```
@echo off
```

ask user to enter file name:

```
set /p file="Enter your filename: "
```

call the command:

```
g++ -o %file%.exe %file%.cpp
```